# Is it possible to maintain two connections at the same time, where the one connection is parked (on hold) and second is active, along with switching

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We have a scenario where we are using Twilio SDK for voice calling and we encountered a situation where we want to establish 2 or more than 2 connections at the same time.

for example -

1. Agent received an incoming call and accepted it (customer1 and agent leg both active).
2. Agent received another incoming call and wants to accepts it (without disconnecting the current call - maybe on hold).

Right now we are not able to do it because when we try to establish a different connection Twilio throws error for "Already active connection".

And we don't seem to find a way to maintain both the connection at the time.

To create a new connection we use - `

> Twilio.Device.connect()

`

Can someone please help if it is even possible in Twilio to do the same, or any other approach to tackle this situation.